# Expectation of $\dfrac{1}{\overline{X}}$

Tags: probability, statistics

Problem: Let $X$ be a random variable where it density function is given by $f_X(x,\theta) = \dfrac{1}{\theta}x^{-1-\frac{1}{\theta}}$, if $x\ge 1$ and $0$, otherwise. What is the expectation of $\dfrac{1}{\overline{X}}$, where $\overline{X}$ is the $n$-sample mean.

I have tried to use the moment generating function to solve this problem but it seem doesn't work. Anyone can show me some hints to deal with this problem?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe this has a closed-form answer?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut I have search for a lot of relative result but it seems we do not have a general closed form for this problem. That's why I want to ask for a solution to this particular problem.

Comment: Your density is a version of the Pareto distribution, which does not have moment generating functions as for any $\theta$ some of its moments are infinite